# Double results differ in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, double

I found some weird things in my code while playing a few of numbers.

Here is the code I am working on.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double f1,f2;

    cout << "Enter the floating number" << endl;
    cin >> f1;

    f2 = 0.00255;

    return 0;
}
```

Adding a breakpoint before `return`, I checked the value of `f1` and `f2`.

Then, I found a difference between `f1` and `f2`, even though they must be identical.

Below is what I compared in the debugging mode.

[image]

- Q1. Why are those values different?

  The difference is so marginal that they seem identical as 0.00255 but sometimes that small difference could be important in mathematical application.
- Q2. How can I make them identical as 0.0025500000000000002?

Comment: *I found some weird things in my code while playing a few of numbers.* -- This is not weird, unless you are not aware that binary floating point is not decimal.

Comment: @NathanOliver this duplicate does explain inaccuracies in **floating-point math**, but no explicit  math is being performed in this question.  What is being observed here is probably not an artifact of IEEE-754, but more likely an artifact of Intel-compatible CPUs sometimes using 80 bit floats that get truncated to 64-bit iff stored in memory.

Comment: @DrewDormann `cin` has to convert the text the user entered into a number.  That involves math.

Comment: *How can I make them identical as 0.0025500000000000002?* -- The question to you is why you want them identical, down to the last digit of precision?  What type of applications are you developing?  Financial?  Scientific?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it affects subsequent calculation. The application is in scientific area.

Comment: @9mile, the answer you may be looking for is that applications that require exact mathematical precision should not use [types that are inexact](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_exact).  `double` is fast, at the cost of this inaccuracy.

Comment: As noted, if you want exact math, then use a third-party, exact type that supports fixed point math (or a big integer number library).  For example, applications that usually need exact types are financial based.  Scientific applications rarely, if ever need the full precision, and can withstand the least significant set of digits being "off".

Comment: @Drew Dormann, Paul Mckenzie,  i undersatand what you  mean. I will search types for my study.